# Is there supposed to be a piece of rubber in the SD slot on a chromebook? I have one

Tags: chromebook

I have a chromebook with a piece of rubber in the slot on the back.  Is this supposed to be there?  It doesn't want to come out.  I stuck a microSD card in it thinking it was another card slot and now I can't retrieve it.  (my bad).  Is there a solution to this problem, or is the card just gone?

Comment: Which Chromebook?

Answer (score 3):

That is the the 3g SIM slot,but unless you have the 3g model it is just a dummy hole because it Samsung makes the same case for all the Chromebooks and blocks the non-3g enabled models with a little rubber bumper.  You probably hear your micro SDHC card rattling around in there.  You will probably have to open the case to retrieve it.

Comment: Yeah, it's rattling around inside.  I'd like to do that, but will any components come loose and then I'll have trouble getting it back together?  I took all the screws out, and then found that I needed to force it loose to open it.  At this point, I chickened out, and screwed it back together.  I don't want to make it worse.

Answer (score 1):

On the back of my Samsung Chromebook, cheap one, not the 550, there are 4 slots on the back.  Three are labeled, one has a door.  There is an HDMI, a SS USB, and a normal USB.  The one with a door that looks like it has a rubber piece already in it is a SIM slot for what could have been 3G or 4G broadband.  This door is to the left of all the other ports.  The SD card slot is on the left side of the system and is labeled SD.  I don't know of any Chromebook right off hand that has a MicroSD slot and especially not on the back.  All of them seem to have the SD or memory card slots on the left or right side.

What model do you have and what is the slot labeled?

Comment: no label on this slot, I'm thinking it's for the broadband card.  Does your broadband slot have a piece of rubber in it?  It seems like protection from dust, but it doesn't come out.  The slot is so thin you can't get a tweezer into it, but my micro hd is in there somewhere.

Comment: My chromebook says model # XE303C12 on the bottom.

Comment: When I fold the unit up and shake it, I can hear something loose inside.  I think I didn't put it in the slot; I put it on the wrong side of that little rubber strip and it's now inside the unit.  Probably I could open it up and retrieve it.  Has anyone ever removed all the screws on the bottom and opened one up?  Maybe a laptop repair person could confidently open this up and retrieve the item?

Comment: Yep, that's the SIM slot on the $250 Samsung.  Not at all sure whether the slot leads to an open area or if the socket is sealed.  The rubber seems to be something to seal the slot.  Tugged at it and it stretched, but didn't seem to want to come out.

Comment: Yeah, mine stretches too, but doesn't come out.  I'm thinking about taking it to a laptop repair person and ask them to open it and see if they can get the little card out.  This is over my head.

Answer (score 0):

Having followed youtube directions for XE303C12-A01U complete disassembly, I can confirm that if your SIM slot has a black rubber blocking access it's because that model is WiFi only and lacks the SIM hardware.  I was hoping they blocked it for legal reasons (regional contracts or T-Mobile contractual obligations) but no such luck :(